# iPhone: Invalid Characters in filesystem

Tags: iphone, filesystems, nsfilemanager

is the iPhone's filesystem or the use of NSFilemanager restricted to any characters or is everything allowed (this is what I'm currently assuming after doing some research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone OS is derived from BSD. Thus as in other Unix'es the only characters forbidden in individual path elements are '/' and obviously '\0'. Everything else is allowed.

Comment: I thought colons were forbidden too?